# SQL Server 2017 installation failed

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, sql-server-2017-express

When I try to install SQL Server 2017, I get an error:

[This Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nxzy2.png)

I did delete SQL Server 2008 R2 and c++ redistributable 2017, but the error is the same.

And this is the [log folder screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5aMg.png)

I don't know how to use the log folder

Comment: check the error logs in that directory... this is pretty impossible to diagnose from across the ether.

Answer (score 0):

1. first log folder delete(log folder means folded location which show in screen shot)
2. team folder clear
3. program install time create folder delete
4. delete in this location folder C:\Users\pc name\Documents\SQL Server Management Studio

then re-try to install.
i hope solve your problem

Comment: I was try to delete C:\Users\pc name\Documents\SQL Server Management Studio but the result is same

Comment: your file may be corrupted . Pls check different pc (for sql 2017 file checking)

Comment: im fail to install sql server 2017 but that instance already installed, how i remove it, i was delete the log file, but the instance still there.